# TADOQuery : Passing null as parameter and getting the resultset

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-7, ado

I am working on Delphi7 and SQlserver 2008 R2.
i have a table with some data like below.\

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tstTable (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Eid int null,
    Pid int null
);

insert into tstTable(Name,Eid,Pid) values ('name1',1,null);
insert into tstTable(Name,Eid,Pid) values ('name2',2,null);
insert into tstTable(Name,Eid,Pid) values ('name3',3,null);
insert into tstTable(Name,Eid,Pid) values ('name4',null,4);
insert into tstTable(Name,Eid,Pid) values ('name5',null,5);
insert into tstTable(Name,Eid,Pid) values ('name4',null,6);
insert into tstTable(Name,Eid,Pid) values ('name7',null,null);
```

now i want to get the record where Eid is equal to 1. in sql server i am able to get the result.

[image: Sql result]

when i try the same in delphi i am not getting any result.
in Delphi, i have taken TADOConnection, TADOQuery, TDataSource and TDBGrid.

```
SET TADOQuery.Query = 'select Name from tstTable where Eid=:Eid and Pid =:Pid'

  with ADOQuery1 do
  begin
    Parameters.ParamByName('Eid').Value := 1;
    Parameters.ParamByName('pid').Value := NULL;//i tried with Unassigned also
    Close;
    open;
  end; //with
```

when i open the AdoQuery, in grid it is not showing any records.
below code is also not returning any records.

```
  with ADOQuery1 do
  begin
    Parameters.ParamByName('Eid').Value := NULL;
    Parameters.ParamByName('pid').Value := NULL;//i tried with Unassigned also
    Close;
    open;
  end; //with
```

how to handle this scenario?

Comment: Use `AND Pid IS NULL`. `NULL` is not a value. It's a state of no value.

Comment: @Victoria : i tried that. it is failing when i want to pass all the parameters are null. when we have a record like  "insert into tstTable(Name,Eid,Pid) values ('name7',null,null);"

Comment: `where something = null` just doesn't work. Only `IS` and `IS NOT` can return true when comparing something with null. The other operators always return false. You say it works in SQL server, but it doesn't. You're executing a different query there, where (probably) that whole condition is omitted.

Comment: @GolezTrol : it is working in SQl server 2008 r2.

Comment: Could you please test that again? The query from the screenshot should *not* return results at all. Maybe you didn't run the full query, or the tool you used performs some magic, but that query as-is should not return anything. It's a basic rule of SQL, and normally you would need [stuff like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951099/how-to-compare-null-values-from-the-database-column) to work around it.

Comment: Maybe your [`SET ANSI_NULLS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql) is set to `OFF` in the SSMS? You could use that to use `=` and `<>` operators with null, but I don't recommend it since in a future version, `ANSI_NULLS` will always be `ON`. use `IS NULL` as already suggested.

Comment: please catch the exact sql statement that is send to the database using the sql server profiler. That is the only way to be 100% sure what sql command is being send to the database. Then try that command in SSMS

Comment: Also, your query cannot work. You cannot do value = null. Sql cannot use the = operator on null values

Comment: @GuidoG, not unless you specify `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;` which does work with `=` operator on `NULL` values.

Comment: @kobik Yes, but I cannot see that he has specified `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF anywhere`

Comment: @GuidoG, Yes, me neither. it might be the database default? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070913/database-options-why-by-default-set-ansi-nulls-off-is-off-for-new-databases

Answer (score 1):

I can say that the query you provide in the image return (0) rows if **[SET ANSI_NULLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql)** is `ON`:

You can try to use set it to `OFF`:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;');     
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('select Name from tstTable where Eid=:Eid and Pid =:Pid');
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Eid').Value := 1;
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('pid').Value := NULL;
  ADOQuery1.Open;    
end;
```

Tested in: Delphi V7 (Build 4.453).

Comment: you dont have to send the SET ANSI_NULLS OFF as a sepearate command, just put it in front of the 'select' statement that will also work and save you an extra command

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You shouldn't assign anything to the parameter but clear it to set it NULL</strike>

```
Parameters.ParamByName('Eid').Clear;
```

Upd. Unfortunately, this doesn't work with TADOxxx components because TParameter doesn't have Clear() method.

So the solution

```
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM mytable');
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE mycol = :Param1 OR (:Param1 IS NULL AND mycol IS NULL)';
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Param1').Attributes :=
    ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Param1').Attributes + [paNullable];
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Param1').Value := Null();
  ADOQuery1.Open;
```

Tested OK with Delphi 7/SQL Server 2014

Try do not change any SET ANSI_XXX settings because of compatibility issues and the global session scope. If you **really** need to change session default settings, do it at the connection start. When `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` is executed before the query, this will change the setting for the entire session (connection).

Comment: There is no `TParameter.Clear` method for `TADOQuery`.

Comment: Exactly, Clear() is absent for ADO components. I added the solution.

Comment: Is my solution works for you? I see that the solution above requires global ANSI setting change.
Parameter.Clear() is the recommended method to set its value to NULL. You should always use it normally.